# jest test with xmljs GLOBAL not defined

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

currently I am writing an App using

- NodeJS v13.12.0
- Jest 25.4.0
- [xmljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmljs) 0.3.2
- typescript 3.8.3
- ts-jest 25.4.0

This App should mimic a CalDAV Server. For this reason, I rely on the module xmljs, which is (after my research) the only module giving me a direct `path` method for finding properties in the XML.

In the node Container, the App runs fine without any errors. But When I start a test with Jest, the test fails with the error

```
ReferenceError: GLOBAL is not defined
      at node_modules/xmljs/core.js:46:2
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/xmljs/core.js:176:3)
      at node_modules/xmljs/XmlParser.js:3:11
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/xmljs/XmlParser.js:204:3)
```

I now know, that this error originates from the xmljs module trying to set the `GLOBAL` variable, which in NodeJS resolved to `global`. But this does not happen in jest.

My code works like following:

```js
import XmlParser = require("xmljs");

/*
* data is the body of a PROPFIND request
*/
new XmlParser({ strict: true }).parseString(data, (err, xmlNode) => {
    // omit err
    xmlNode.path(["propfind", "prop"], true);

    const propertiesObj: XmlNode[] = childs[0].children;
    const properties: string[] = [];

    Object.keys(propertiesObj).forEach(n => {
        properties.push(n);
    });

    logger.silly("Returning properties: %O", properties);
});
```

Can anyone

1. Show me a module to use instead without requiring huge modifications of my code

   - Which supports a pure js implementation without using node-gyp (since it may be used on windows server)
2. Show me how to make a workaround in jest to spoof this GLOBAL variable being set in xmljs

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of `GLOBAL` in the setup of your tests. It seems that the `GLOBAL` variable is the deprecated form of the `global` in node.

In your `jest.config.js` file you can add a setup file through the [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) option:

```
module.exports = {
    [...] // Other configurations
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/define-deprecated-global.js']
};
```

And in the file `define-deprecated-global` you can define the `GLOBAL` variable as:

```
global.GLOBAL = global;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tries using the beforeAll hook. But this one wasn't working. This method now finally works. Thank you!